# Data Transformation Tools

Tags: etl

HI
Are there any free comparison papers for ETL tools.

thanks
Ben

Comment: Hate to do this, but search for "etl tools compare" before posting

Comment: you need to accept answers to your questions if you want more people to respond

Comment: i did search but not able to find any quality free comparisons across the board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/) from Pentaho is an open source ETL tool that you can look into. Here are some comarision links

1. http://www.jonathanlevin.co.uk/2008/03/open-source-etl-tools-vs-commerical-etl.html
2. Commercial: http://www.etltool.com/
3. comparision from pentaho itself: http://www.pentaho.com/docs/informatica_pentaho_etl_tools_comparison.pdf